# create custom button animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to create custom button with animation. When user touches button it fills with blue shape from left to right (I have done this with `CAShapeLayer` and `CABasicAnimation`). But also while shape fills button I need to change button text color (only letters that shape already reached, from left to right).

Comment: Show code for CAShapeLayer and CABasicAnimation which is use to get fill blue shape button.

Comment: see my answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822531/how-to-make-the-different-colour-appearance-while-layer-color-of-the-view-is-cha